# rotate a matrix such that each element is shifted by one place in a clockwise manner in python

Tags: python

I want to rotate a matrix such that each element is shifted by one place in a clockwise manner.
First it should ask the size of matrix and then matrix elements
Input 3*3 matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
4 1 2
7 5 3
8 9 6
```

Input 4*4 matrix:

```
1  2  3   4
5  6  7   8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Output:

```
5  1   2  3
9  10  6  4
13 11  7  8
14 15 16 12
```

Comment: i tried but i failed as i am a new prgrammer

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-matrix-elements/

Comment: @thei its okay, we all fail atleast once, what we wanted is, what you tried? It could be a wrong code, no issue, we all here to help :)